# Comparing address of array in C++11

Tags: c++, c++11

I just coded

```
 std::array<std::array<double,3>,27 > dshape;
 &dshape[0][0] points to the address ****780
 &dshape[0][1]  points to the address ****788
 &dshape[0][2]  points to the address ****790 (I was expecting 796)
```

Why is that?

Answer (score 10):

> (I was expecting 796)

It's just hexadecimal notation, not decimal.

So

```
0x780 + 0x008 = 0x788
0x788 + 0x008 = 0x790
```

> Why is that?

The `std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, void*)` overload prints hexadecimal value representations by default.

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing you are using `cout` to output the address, and since it's an address it's going to be displayed in `hexadecimal`.

```
0x790 - 0x788 = 0x08
```

which is equal to: (in decimal)

```
1936 - 1928 = 8
```